# How to clear MUI Autocomplete field from parent?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

```
//PARENT COMPONENT

const App = () => {
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState({
    //field id and names
    soldTo:"",
    soldToName:"",      
});

const handleChangeAuto = (name, value) => {
    setFilterData({
      ...filterData,
      soldTo: value !== null ? value.id : "",
      soldToName: value !== null ? value.name : "",
    });
  };

const removeTag = () => {
    setFilterData({ ...filterData, soldTo: "", soldToName: "" });
  };
return (<>
<FilterAutoCompleteField
                  label="Sold To"
                  name="soldTo"
                  value={filterData.soldToName}
                  onChangeAuto={handleChangeAuto}
/>
</>)

**<Button onClick={removeTag}>Reset</Button>**
```

The main App component has filterData state and handleChangeAuto function that is used to assign the Autocomplete data to the filter.

Then in parent "App" component, Reset button triggers the removeTag function, which clears the filter value. Which should reset Autocomplete Text field but it doesn't do so.

```
//CUSTOM AUTOFIELD COMPONENT
const FilterAutoCompleteField = ({
  label,
  name,
  value,
  onChangeAuto,
}) => {
  data=[{id:0, name:"yo"},{id:1, name:"hello"}, {id:2, name:"wow"}]

  const { id } = useId();
 

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
      <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        id={id}
        options={data}
        value={value}
        inputValue={value}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          onChangeAuto(name, newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

When I click reset button, in console window "filterData" is reset but AutoComplete textfield still has the old field. It's like FilteredAutoComplete field is not updated or rendered.

I tried passing null value inside removeTag. That too didn't work.

**EDIT:Here, I passed the soldTo and soldTo items in filterData.   But that object is passed dynamically through a variable. And that's causing it to not render that section.How to fix that while passing filterObject in filterData state.**

```
 const filterObject = [{soldTo:"", soldToName:""}]
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = React.useState({
    //field id and names
    // soldTo: '',
    // soldToName: '',
    ...filterObject
  });
```

Although filterData state is changed. Text in Autocomplete is not cleared. Here is the link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8d5hed?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: at line 41 if you split the array, it will create a state as { 0: { soldTo: '', soldToName: '' } }, which is the wrong DS, cause autocomplete to receive the wrong data of undefined beacuse filterData.soldToName it will result undefined. define your useState as  const [filterData, setFilterData] = React.useState({ soldTo: '', soldToName: '' })

Answer (score 0):

I just find a error at compile time and i've made some adjustment, the code is fine itself.
Adjustment that i did:

- make right declaration of the variable data `const data = ....`
- remove state spreading on set State
- remove useId hook

here the link of the code : [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wgeqxf?file=src%2FApp.js)

maybe one other thing that you could check is the component import

Comment: Thank you. I will implement the suggested changes when i'll have access to the code after 2 days. I'll let you know if it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, can you please look at my code, @thekritsakon? I've added context to the question.